# Is there any way to use JavaScript on wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com

Can someone tell me how to use JavaScript on wordpress.com? Is it even possible? I want to have a wave on a page, but the required JavaScript is stripped.

Comment: What do you mean by a Wave?

Comment: @Scott: I think he's talking about [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the official support documents, no.

http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/

> **Javascript**
>
> Users are not allowed to post JavaScript on WordPress.com blogs. JavaScript can be used for malicious purposes. As an example, JavaScript has taken down sites such as MySpace.com and LiveJournal offline in the past. The security of all the blogs is a top priority and until we can guarantee scripting languages will not be harmful they will not be permitted.